# Replace Element When Clicked On 3 Times Won't Work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, replace, element

I wrote short javascript code to replace an element after 3 clicks on it. After it exceeds 3 clicks the element replaces itself with the url one. But the problem is it won't work. I tried to make it replace itself after 3 click but, I might of coded it wrongly. Please enlighten me.

Original Code:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = this.responseText;   
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://natevanghacks.com/replacements/yoinkexecutor2.html"), true;
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Re-coded to work for 3 clicks only and doesn't work:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let count = 0;
  let callback = function() {
    count++;  
    if (count >= 3) {
      document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = this.responseText;  
    }
    iframe1.click(callback);  
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://natevanghacks.com/replacements/yoinkexecutor2.html"), true;
    xhttp.send();
  }
};
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You can use fetch instead of the old XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You have a strange comma expression after xhttp.open()

Comment: It won't replace the element for the url one. Might be a better idea to use fetch though hah, XMLHttpRequest was the only thing i found on the web. So, I am not sure what the problem with the code is.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but why do you check for `>= 1` if you want to check against 3?

Comment: Also, `count` will always be reset to zero when the function gets called, so the chances of getting that to 3 are slim to none...

Comment: haha, might of overlooked that for no reason, I edited the post for that now. Otherwise am not too fond, but there has to be a issue with the code since it doesn't show the errors in the console anymore. It just won't replace the element.

Comment: Yeah, because 3 can't be reached with your code

Comment: alright, welp I gotta find a new method.

Comment: have a look here, that might help https://jsfiddle.net/x5fe3gjo/

Comment: Also, some more extensive help on the topic: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: thanks for being useful, may god help us.

Answer (score 1):

Set `count` as global variable means outside of function:

```
let count = 0;
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  let callback = function() {
    count++;  
    if (count >= 3) {
      document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = this.responseText;  
    }
    iframe1.click(callback);  
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://natevanghacks.com/replacements/yoinkexecutor2.html"), true;
    xhttp.send();
  }
};
```

When you define `count` inside the  function then every time count reset to its default value 0

That's why you need to define `count` outside of function.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work though, I click on the element 3 times and doesn't replace it.

Comment: Add `count++; if (!(count >= 3)) {return;}` in first line of function